# Store and pass variadic arguments in golang?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

Here's the use case: I'm trying to dynamically build variadic arguments (which means I need to store them), then I need to pass them to a variadic function. The function has the signature below. And the failing code is below. What is the proper way to do this?

```
// variadic function
func Select(dest interface{}, query string, args ...interface{}) error

//failing code
var args = make([]interface{}, 0, 5)

func add(params ...interface{}) {
   args = append(args, params)
}

Select(&dest, query, args...)

//error is sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to apply the spread operator on the add function as well. 
The error code seems a bit strange but the correct code should look like this:

```
var args = make([]interface{}, 0, 5)

func add(params ...interface{}) {
   args = append(args, params...)
}

Select(&dest, query, args...)
```